# asp.net range validator on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:textbox` with both required and range validators attached to it, where the code looks like this:

ASP:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" MaximumValue="1" MinimumValue="0"
     ValidationGroup="valid" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Out of Range" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1"
     ValidationGroup="valid" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Cannot be blank" />
```

And when the page is dynamically loaded (after a quick callback), I have code that is supposed to change the `MaximumValue` of the RangeValidator to more specific value. Here is the code for that:

```
rangeValidator1.MaximumValue = GetMaxValue(params).ToString();
```

Now, I have set a breakpoint, and `rangeValidator1.MaximumValue` is being set correctly, however, when the page loads, and I look at the compiled client side javascript, it appears that the maximum value is still only 1.

What confuses me more is that any integer typed in will pass, as long as the first digit is a '1'. So if the maxValue is *supposed* to be something like "1234567", "1" will match, as will "12345678910". But "2" will not. Nor will "3000" or "46000".

Has anyone else had a similar issue with RangeValidators on Textboxes?

Comment: textbox1 does not appear to be in the same ValidationGroup and the id is textBox1 (note the capital B) Is that just a typo here?

Comment: Also, doesn't RangeValidator have a Type field?

Comment: in regards to your first comment, sorry, that was a typo. I changed the ids when I copied the code over to SO so that it was easier to read. They *do* match up.

Comment: and in regards to your second comment...adding `Type="Integer"` fixed it right up. Thanks. If you want to post that as the answer...I'll accept it.

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6962947/310112

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The RangeValidator handles validation for multiple types. You should make sure to set the Type to Integer. or what ever is appropriate.